# how to assign data from database to dxlooktreeview?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

saving data from the component to database work great

```
dm.tabtier.FieldByName('clefamtiers').Asinteger:=dm.tabfamtiers.FieldByName('clefamtiers').AsInteger;
tabfamtiers is datasource of dxlookuptreeview
```

i need to show data from database to dxlookuptreeview but i can't make it go right ,
if condition found record then locate and show it

```
dxlookuptreeview1.text:=dm.tabfamtiers.FieldByName('famtiers').AsString
dxlookuptreeview1.rootvalue:=dm.tabtier.FieldByName('clefamtiers').Asinteger
```

but it did not work

Comment: Why not using dxDbLookupTreeView?

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe you should consider calling Devexpress support center?